# Confusing sequence of code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I am attempting to use HTML Agility Pack to do parsing on some webpages. 
here is a line of code I came across in an example.

```
var div = document.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(n => n.Name == "div")
```

the tooltip says "(parameter) HTMLNode n" when placed over n in visual Studio

I am uncertain what n is and what this line does

Answer (score 1):

This code selects all the descendants of the root node of the document with tag name == "div"

- **document.DocumentNode** selects the root node
- **.Descendants()** selects all the nodes in the root node (not only direct children but all)
- **.Where()** selects only those who meets some criteria
- **n => n.Name == "div"** is the criteria itself that means "if n is a node then the criteria is true when node's **Name** is equal to **"div"**

Comment: But what exactly is occuring in each part of the statement? like what is (n=> n.Name = "div")